# scoop update,download fail: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time

Tags: google-chrome, scoop-installer

The error happens when running the command `scoop download googlechrome` or  `scoop update googlechrome`

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. [::ffff:172.217.24.78]:443 (dl.google.com:443)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

The site is blocked in some areas. Opening a proxy tool can solve it.